# typescript package visibility (create library)

Tags: angular, typescript, package, declare

I'm creating  a typescript library to be used in different project.
What I want is to publish for external only a subset of my class functions and use the others internally in my library.

In the example:

```
/* Person.ts */
export class Person{
    getName(){
        .....
        return name;
    } 
    getInfos(){

    }
}

/* People.ts */
export class People{
    ...
    setName(){
       let p = new Person();
       ...
       let n = p.getName();
       ....
    }

}
```

I would that my library expose Person getInfos() and People setName() but I want that Person getName is accessible only internally.
Maybe I've to create a Person.d.ts that expose only one method to the external users but I do not understand how.

Thanks

Comment: Note that `People` class would access to _getName()_ method, so set it as `private` is not the solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have library with `d.ts` files without specific method you can do the following

**parson.ts**

```
export class Person{
  /** @internal */ <== annotate field with internal flag
  private getName(){
    return name;
  }
  /** @internal */ <== annotate field with internal flag
  public getName2(){
    return name;
  }
  getInfos(){

  }
}
```

Then tell compiler do not emit declarations for code that has an `/** @internal */` JSDoc annotation by specifying `stripInternal` compile option

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "declaration": true,
    "stripInternal": true, <== this option
```

The output should be as follows

**person.d.ts**

```
export declare class Person {
  getInfos(): void;
}
```

So typescript skipped all fields annotated with `/** @internal */` even with `public` modificator

Angular uses the same method when is building project

Comment: But `People` class can access to getName method?

Comment: As @Maximus said `in JavaScript everything is public`. So `const people = new People(); (people as any).getName()` should work. My solution is suitable for compile time

Comment: I known that in js is all public, I interested to encapsulation at compile time. 
My goal is to create a library and allow the others developers to use only some methods in my classes (as I do with _package_ modifier in Java).
I think that your solution is not enough

Comment: @Maximus  Sorry, I meant getName2..
I try your code:
- If I use internal annotation, I have a ts error (Cannot find name 'internal'). I have to import something ?
- If I create manually the Person.d.ts file, from outside this module, ts allow me to use also person.getName2(). In my test Person.d.ts and person.ts is in the same folder..

Comment: I don't know how you are building your library. i adhere to Angular Package Format v4.0 https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CZC2rcpxffTDfRDs6p1cfbmKNLA6x5O-NtkJglDaBVs/edit

Comment: see the app.ts in this plunker:  [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/NVFbSKTbhj6Uh7MFcsv2?p=preview)

Comment: In the app showed, the _getName_ is accessible because ts take the Person.ts and do not consider Person.d.ts, If I move Person.ts in another folder, I have a compile error...

Comment: Your library will be located inside node_modules. And all typings should be available

Comment: That means that I have to package and publish my library on npm..
But if I want to use my library internally (simply the lib is in a subfolder) it's not possible?

Comment: Check my library example https://github.com/alexzuza/angular-package-format-library/blob/master/src/tsconfig.json#L16 I use alias to test my library

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zuz/lib Here is also good article about building such libraries https://medium.com/@trekhleb/how-to-create-aot-jit-compatible-angular-4-library-with-external-scss-html-templates-9da6e68dac6e

Comment: Actually it is discouraged to hide privates from the declaration file. Otherwise you could derive from that class, declare a private of your own with the same name, and unknowingly stomp on your base class's private variable value. That failure mode would be very, very difficult to debug (quotation from [this TS issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1867#issuecomment-209018980))

Answer (score 1):

You have to distinguish between compile time and runtime encapsulation. If you just need a compile time encapsulation, you can use the approach suggested by @trichetriche and declare `getName` as private or use a more advanced method by @yurzui.

If you want runtime encapsulation you have to use different approach. If you export a class, it exports all its methods as in JavaScript everything is public. To hide some functionality, you can create a function `getName` in the module but do not expose it. You will be able to use it but it will not be available outside:

```
function getName() {... return name;}

export class Person{
    getInfos(){
        return getName.call(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: in your example, the function getName is indipendent from Person class, so can't access to private var or internal methods.

Comment: @user1439356 `getName` function gets context `this`. You can access to internal methods

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use getName internally and don't export it, simply do

```
/* Person.ts */
export class Person{
    protected getName(){
        return getName();
    } 
    getInfos(){

    }
}

/* People.ts */
export class People extends Person {
    ...
    setName(){
      let p = new Person();
      ...
      let n = p.getName();
      ....
    }

}
```

Comment: this will still be accessible in JS though

Comment: Is that a problem ?

Comment: it depends on what the OP wants, runtime encapsulation or compile time

Comment: If the method is private, the `People` class can't use it.
I need a kind of  _"package"_ method, in a way that all classes in my library can use it, but external project use only the public methods.

Comment: @trichetriche, it won't help because all classes would have to extend the base class to use `protected`.

Comment: @user1439356, the approach I showed allows you doing that.

Comment: That's the point. Make a mother class that has the method, and use the children classes to call it.

Comment: @trichetriche, sorry, but it doesn't make sense. Why put up a class hierarchy just to be able to access the method if ES6 modules encapsulation allows that?

Comment: I didn't know ES6 encapsulation allowed that, this is what I learnt in school and what I used until now.

Comment: By ES6 modules encapsulation I meant defining module private functions, not private fields on classes

Comment: _trichetriche_ you have forced that People extends Person and I don't want this.
@Maximus maybe Module encapsulation is what I find. Can you show an example?

Comment: @user1439356, I showed it in my answer. The function `getName` exists inside the module and can be used anywhere inside the module, but it's not exposed to any other module that imports that module